# Labeling Equations in style (A.1), (A.2), … , (B.1), (B.2), … in the appendix in the amsart document class

Tags: labels, amsart, appendix

I am using the amsart document class, which by default continues the equation labeling in the appendix from the main sections. So if the last equation in an ordinary section would be (35), the first equation in the Appendix would be (36).

I would like the appendix equations to be prelabeled with the letter of the appendix section though. I.e., I would like the first equation of Appendix A be labeled (A.1), the second (A.2), and then the same with Appendix B.

If the numbers in appendix B then continue from those of appendix A, or restart from 1 again is not so important actually. But it would also be good to know how that can be customised, if someone happens to know.

When I google for it, I do find solutions, which however do not use the amsart document class. And this sounds like something which may already be built in.

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Please show us a short compilable tex code you tried so far !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard methods work fine in this case. The AMS classes provide a `\numberwithin` macro which is equivalent to the `\counterwithin` macro provided in the LaTeX kernel. This resets the numbering (in this case per section). I've removed your `.` in the A.1 for aesthetic reasons. You can add it in as you prefer.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\begin{equation}
x = y^2
\end{equation}
\appendix
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection\arabic{equation}}
%\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}% with dot
\section{An appendix}
\begin{equation}
x = y^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!